# Decompositions from torus actions and compactness of (sub-)level sets

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, morse-theory, torus-action

Let $T=\mathbb{C}^{*}$ act on a smooth complex *quasi*-projective variety $X$. Assume that the limit point $\lim_{t\to 0}t\cdot x$ exists for every $x\in X$.

From the induced $U(1)$-action and its (real) moment map one can cook up a Morse function (or, if the fixed points are not isolated, a Morse-Bott function) $f$ on $X$, whose gradient flow $\varphi_s$ is equal to $\varphi_s (x)=e^{s}\cdot x$ for $s\in\mathbb{R}$ (considering $e^s\in T$). So, in particular, the limit of $s\cdot x$ for $s\to -\infty$ exists for every $x\in X$.

**Edit:** Let $X^{-}$ be the subset of those $x\in X$ for which 
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} t\cdot x$$ 
exists. Assume that $X^-$ is a compact subset of $X$.

> **Q.** Under the above hypotheses, when are the sub-level sets $f^{-1}\left((-\infty,c]\right)$ of $f$ compact for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$? Any references about this?

Comment: One sufficient condition would be that $f$ is bounded below, which is true in many standard examples.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Do you also have a reference for "bounded below is enough"?

Comment: If $f(x) \geq k$ for all $x \in X$  then $f^{-1}((-\infty, c]) = f^{-1}([k,c])$ which is compact. pre-image of compact set by continuous function is compact.

Comment: For standard example one can take any linear action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ (with positive weights!).

Comment: You must be assuming $f$ proper (pre-image of compact set by continuous function is not compact in general!). When is $f$ proper, in the context of the question?

Comment: Ahh yes, you are right (I guess I was assuming $X$ is compact or something). I still think it is enough for $f$ to be bounded below, but I don't see an easy way to prove...

Comment: Ahh I just realised, it is completely false. take the action of $\mathbb{C}^*$ on $\mathbb{C^{2}}$ given by $z(z_{1},z_{2}) = (z_{1},z z_{2})$ then $f(z_{1},z_{2}) = |z_{2}|^{2}$ then $f^{-1}(-\infty,c]$ is not compact for $c > 0$. Sorry for using your comment space with this confusion!

Comment: Thank you, indeed: you made me realize I probably want a further hypothesis on the action. I'll edit right now.